# How to use different fileName patterns based on the lifecycle environment

Tags: java, logging, logback, spring-logback

How to use different versions of logback.xml based on the active spring boot profile

```
src/main/resources/logback.xml
src/main/resources/logback-qa.xml
src/main/resources/logback-staging.xml
src/main/resources/logback-production.xml
```

My intention is to change the fileNamePattern alone based on the environment as well as the file path, I would prefer not to created additional files, if its easier to achieve it with a single file

```
<fileNamePattern>logs/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
<fileNamePattern>logs/app-qa.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
<fileNamePattern>logs/app-staging.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
<fileNamePattern>/logs/app-production.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logback-spring.xml supports ***springProfile*** tag and [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#profile-specific-configuration) recommends to use logback-spring.xml instead of logback.xml.
You can use springProfile tag in logback-spring.xml as follows:

```
<springProfile name="staging">
    <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "staging" profile is active -->
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="dev | staging">
    <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "dev" or "staging" profiles are active -->
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="!production">
    <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "production" profile is not active -->
</springProfile>
```